# array_chunk and ForLoop in Javascript for appending multiple elements in one div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an ajax post, which fetches data from controller and what I want to do is creating a div for each element of array_chunk, and append all divs  of every single chunk into one div (please, see the html below).

```
success: function(data) {
     var posts = data['data'];
     var postsCount = data['per_page'];
     var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
     var eachRow = document.createDocumentFragment();
     var n,j,tempArray,chunk = 3;

        for (n=0,j=posts.length; n<j; n+=chunk) {
            tempArray = posts.slice(n,n+chunk); 

                  // console.log(tempArray); [object],[object],[object] x5

             for(i=0; i < tempArray.length; i++){
                 frag.appendChild(postElem(tempArray));
             }

            var eachRow = document.createElement('div');
            eachRow.className = "row eachRow";
            eachRow.appendChild(frag);
         }
    document.getElementById('content').appendChild(eachRow);
}
```

- This code is producing:

  ```
  <div class="row eachRow">
     <div class="eachPost>_</div> 
  </div>
  <div class="row eachRow">
     <div class="eachPost>_</div> 
  </div>
  <div class="row eachRow">
     <div class="eachPost>_</div> 
  </div>
  ```
- What I want to achieve

  ```
  <div class="row eachRow">
     <div class="eachPost>_</div>
     <div class="eachPost>_</div>
     <div class="eachPost>_</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row eachRow">
     <div class="eachPost>_</div>
     <div class="eachPost>_</div>
     <div class="eachPost>_</div>
  </div>
  ```

---

By the way, `function postElem()` is used to append everything else in `eachPost`.

```
function postElem(posts){
   var eachPost = document.createElement('div');
   eachPost.className = "col-md-4 eachPost";

       //and a big chunk of code that finally appends into `eachPost`.

  return eachPost;
}
```

---

Note that `data`, and `posts` are object. `console.log(posts)` is logging
`[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object...]`

`0: Object`
`1: Object`
`2: Object`
`3: Object`
`4: Object...`

```
0: Object:
     ->name
     ->email // (etc.. It's user table)

     ->posts // (user hasMany() post // eloquent relationship)
         ->created_at
         ->id
         ->comments
              ->id
              ->body
              ->created_at (etc..)

      ->user_profile (also eloquent relationship)
           ->photo
           ->about
```

Comment: do you want to insert 3 `div`s inside each `div`?

Comment: Yes, this is what i want to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

var data = ["Post 1", "Post 2", "Post 3", "Post 4", "Post 5", "Post 6", "Post 7", "Post 8", "Post 9", "Post 10"]

```
var groupedData = [];
 var groupIndex = 0;
 $.each(data, function (index, post) {
     if (index == 0) {
         groupedData[groupIndex] = [];
     }
     else if (index % 3 == 0) {
         groupIndex++;
         groupedData[groupIndex] = [];
     }
     groupedData[groupIndex].push(post);
 });
 $.each(groupedData, function (index, value) {
     var eachRow = document.createElement('div');
     eachRow.className = "row eachRow";
     $.each(value, function (postIndex, post) {
         var postElement = document.createElement('div');
         postElement.className = "eachPost";
         eachRow.appendChild(postElement);
     });

     document.getElementById('content').appendChild(eachRow);
 });
```

**Explanation**

You need to split your data array into multiple arrays and each array having maximum 3 number of post. Now you can easily append these elements to each `row` div.

**Update**

```
var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var obj = {};
    obj.name = "Name " + i;
    obj.posts = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        var post = { id: j };
        obj.posts.push(post);
    }

    data.push(obj);
}
```

is this your data?

Comment: I am having trouble adapting your example to my case, as my data is an object. I tried to convert it into arrays, but that didn't work well because I couldn't access stuff using this kind of calls - `posts[i]['about']['created_at']`. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: @senty Could you please provide an example object of your data?

Comment: I added that part in the question. In that example, let's say I want to access for each object using something like `posts[i][comments][1][body]`. But as posts is an object, I had struggled adapting your example.

Comment: @senty So, your data will be, `data = [object, object, object ..]` instead of `var data = ["Post 1", "Post 2", "Post 3", "Post 4", "Post 5", "Post 6", "Post 7", "Post 8", "Post 9", "Post 10"]`?

Comment: Yes, that's right, so I got lost adapting your example.

Comment: @senty, I have added a code to generate a sample data like you have. please check whether is this correct?

Comment: @senty, If this is a correct sample, then there will be no need to change any code. Then where will you be get stuck?

Comment: Do I need to put your update bit at the top of everything?

Comment: @senty, sure, Feel free to modify my answer to get desired data.